# What's the ideal memory hard function?

Tags: memory-hard

[This](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/027.pdf) says $f_n$ is memory hard if, for any space $S$ and time $T$, $S\cdot T \in \Omega(n^2)$.

My questions:

- What is $S$?  Space?  E.g. bytes of available memory?
- What is $n$?  Bytes of requested memory by the memory hard function?
- What is $T$?  Number of rounds?
- How good is this definition?  E.g. how tight is it?  E.g. $\Omega(n^2)$ is asymptotic lowest bound, but I guess not all functions that are $\in \Omega(n^2)$ are equal.  E.g. perhaps some are better?  So I guess this definition is not tight enough to show us which memory-hard KDF is necessarily better?
- Any better memory-hardness definition? E.g. more tight than simply $\in \Omega(n^2)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of these are addressed in the article. In this setting, the "adversary" is some algorithm that can evaluate $f_n$ using less resources than we had hoped.

- $S$ = space/memory complexity of the adversary. In this line of work, $f_n$ is a function that makes calls to some random oracle $H : \{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}^k$, and $S$ is the (worst-case) space usage of the adversary, measured in $k$-bit "blocks."
- $T$ = time complexity of the adversary. Usually measured in number of calls to $H$. In some models the adversary is allowed to make parallel calls to $H$ for free, so $T$ is the number of "sequential rounds" of calls to $H$.
- $n$ = the tunable hardness parameter of the memory-hard function. Larger $n$ increases the effort required to evaluate the function $f_n$ (and ideally the effort scales quadratically in $n$). Honest parties should choose the largest $n$ such that the they are willing to spend the effort to evaluate $f_n$.

> How good is this definition? ... So I guess this definition is not tight enough to show us which memory-hard KDF is necessarily better?

It's true that $n^2/1000$ is a lot different than $1000n^2$, but this definition would be happy with memory-hard functions with either of these levels of difficulty.
At the time of this paper, most candidate memory-hard functions were *asymptotically* much worse than $\Theta(n^2)$.
So this definition is quite effective to rule out many bad candidates.
Once you have many candidates that satisfy this *asymptotic* definition, then you can start to worry about the constant factors.

> Any better memory-hardness definition?

Yes, this definition only considers the *worst* case space usage $S$.
Suppose $f_n$ is a function that indeed requires $n$ units of memory to evaluate -- there is no way to evaluate $f_n$ without holding $n$ units of memory *at some point.*
This doesn't rule out the possibility that $n$ units of memory are required only for a very short window of time.
In other words, there could be an algorithm for $f_n$ whose plot of memory usage over time looks like this:

[image]

(images taken from [Leo Reyzin's slides on scrypt](https://cs-web.bu.edu/fac/reyzin/papers/BostonCryptoDayTalk-Leo.pptx))

If this algorithm has *maximum* space usage $n$ and also uses $n$ time, its ST-complexity is $\Omega(n^2)$.
ST-complexity is like the area of the blue bounding-box rectangle in this picture.

But this measure of memory-hardness obscures some problem.
Suppose an adversary wants to evaluate $f_n$ on many different inputs, and it cleverly schedules those evaluations like this:

[image]

This strategy can be used to evaluate the example $f_n$ on $n$ different inputs using only $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ total memory!
So the total "ST-cost" to evaluate the function $n$ times is $O(n^2)$, meaning that the *amortized* cost per instance is only $O(n)$.

A better way to classify the memory-hardness of a function would be to measure the **area under the curve** rather than the area of the bounding box.
This is indeed what is proposed in [subsequent works](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/875.pdf), where the memory-hardness-metric is called "cumulative memory complexity."

Comment: nice answer, I learnt quite a bit from it.

Comment: Yes, people forgot the amortized cost many times. And, this is why memory-hard functions need random access all the time.